# Batch Script - Skip on errorlevel in a For loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, errorlevel

I am trying to have this script go to the next part if the error level of a ping to a computer does not equal 0, but I cannot get it to work. The output says the syntax is not correct. Thank you.

```
@echo
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%a in (main.txt)  do ( 
ping -n 1 %%a > NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (GOTO :COPY) ELSE GOTO :SKIP

:COPY
ROBOCOPY C:\Blah C:\Bloh
ECHO FILE COPIED

:SKIP
 ECHO FILE NOT COPIED
 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
@echo
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%a in (main.txt) do ( 
  ping -n 1 %%a >NUL
  IF "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
    ROBOCOPY "C:\Blah" "C:\Bloh"
    ECHO FILE COPIED
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO FILE NOT COPIED
  )
)
PAUSE
```

There are a couple of things wrong with your code. First of all, you enable Delayed Expansion, but don't actually use it, only variables inside `!` get expanded delayed. I also put quotes around your filepaths, to protect them against paths with spaces and stuff. Finally, `goto` and labels don't work inside `for` loops, so you need to replace them with `if else` logic

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, this works the way I needed it. You explained it very well and I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

`goto :Label` inside a parenthesised block of code like `for` loops breaks the block/loop context, so the code at the label is executed as if it were outside of the block/loop. Therefore you need to work around that.

---

[Dennis van Gils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897449) points out a way how to do it -- using `if`/`else` logic (his method as well as the following slightly modified snippet (applying numeric comparison) both require [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for "usebackq" /F %%A in ("main.txt") do (
    > nul ping -n 1 %%A
    if !ErrorLevel! EQU 0 (
        robocopy "C:\Blah" "C:\Bloh"
        echo FILE COPIED
    ) else (
        echo FILE NOT COPIED
    )
)
endlocal
```

Or like this, avoiding the necessity of [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
for "usebackq" /F %%A in ("main.txt") do (
    > nul ping -n 1 %%A
    if ErrorLevel 1 (
        echo FILE NOT COPIED
    ) else (
        robocopy "C:\Blah" "C:\Bloh"
        echo FILE COPIED
    )
)
```

---

To check the `ErrorLevel` against (non-)zero, you can also use the `&&` and `||` [operators](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```
for "usebackq" /F %%A in ("main.txt") do (
    > nul ping -n 1 %%A || (
        echo FILE NOT COPIED
    ) && (
        robocopy "C:\Blah" "C:\Bloh"
        echo FILE COPIED
    )
)
```

---

Finally, if you do want to keep the `goto :Label` structure, you need to use a sub-routine in order to move this part of the code outside of the `()` block (you also do not need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) here):

```
for "usebackq" /F %%A in ("main.txt") do (
    > nul ping -n 1 %%A
    call :SUB "C:\Blah" "C:\Bloh"
)
exit /B

:SUB
if %ErrorLevel% NEQ 0 goto :SKIP
robocopy "%~1" "%~2"
echo FILE COPIED
:SKIP
goto :EOF
```